# Azure blob storage - duplicate file issue

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, winscp

I'm facing weird issue. I have one Azure Blob storage container which consists of 2 folders, let's say folder A and folder B. If I copy the files using WinSCP only to folder A, the file is copied in folder A as well as folder B and vice versa.

I see this issue only using WinSCP with Blob storage and not with Azcopy or Azure storage explorer. Also i don't see this issue with Azure file storage using WinSCP.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you have a better chance of getting an answer to this if you post it on server fault

Comment: Your description is not clear, because WinSCP can not directly transfer files to Azure Blob Storage. So I guess your container of Azure Blob Storage may mount to  the filesystem of Linux distribution, such as Azure Linux VM or HDInsight, then to scp a file to Linux filesystem. Right? Please update your post to help us to understand your real environment, purpose and operations.